# Save Weibull observations in a matrix using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, save, weibull

I wrote codes to simulate Weibull values based on 8 different shape parameters using for loop. I want to save it in matrix of 365 x 8 and eventually export to csv.

My code is this:

```
k <- seq(1.4,2.8,0.2)
test <- matrix(rep(NA,365),nrow=365,ncol=8)
for (i in k){
  wind.k <- mapply(rweibull,i,scale.k,MoreArgs=list(n=1))
  test[ ]<-as.matrix(wind.k)
}
```

The result is in 365 x8 but I notice that it only captures k=2 for every column.
Could anyone help fix the codes?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: What value does `scale.k` take?

Comment: What are you achieving with the brackets in `test[ ]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
test <- matrix(rweibull(n=365*8, shape=k, scale=scale.k), nrow=365, ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)
```

Note that `scale.k` must be a length 8 vector.